# Best practice to implement a Git hook on dockerized application with PHP

Tags: php, docker, continuous-integration, githooks

I am pretty new to Docker and just dockerized my PHP application.

On my local computer when I push all the new commits I run some tests with PHPUnit on the pre-push hook.

What is the best practice for implementing this hook with docker environment?

I thought about copule options,

### Option 1:

Creating an 'App' container that is linked to the PHP container and only commit code through it.

The disadvantage of this option is that I have to only handle the commits with a container terminal, could be quite annoying and limiting.

### Option 2:

Using in the hook script the `docker exec` syntax on the PHP container.

**What is the best practice for this situation?**

Comment: I would go with option 2. Keep your repository and git hooks on your host system obviously and either execute your unit tests within your dev container or, when your distribution process gets more complicated (generate/publish API doc, unit-tests, integration tests, code analysis, etc.), create a dedicated release image; A dedicated image has the advantage, that your commit hook does not have dependencies to running containers or anything else and just runs whatever it needs to run;